# Find the minimum using lagrange

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I've got the formula $$x^3+y^3+z^3$$

With the constraint $ax+by+cz = 1$

I tried to solve this using lagrange but every possible way I try to use does not get me to the right answer

Using the lagrange I got to
$$3x^2+ka = 0 $$
$$3y^2+kb = 0 $$
$$3z^2+kc = 0 $$

=

$$3x^2bc+kabc = 0 $$
$$3y^2ac+kabc = 0 $$
$$3z^2ab+kabc = 0 $$

$$z = \sqrt{\frac{cy^2}{b}} $$

$$x = \sqrt{\frac{ay^2}{b}} $$

Fill this in the constraint and I then I cannot figure it out

Any got a clue how to solve this properly?

Comment: What answer do you get when you apply Lagrange in the standard way?

Comment: That's basically the question since I can't figure it out ;/ @lulu

Comment: Well, what happens when you apply Lagrange in the standard way?

Comment: I get that $y = 0$, which means $x = 0$ and $z=0$ but this is not the right answer since $x+y+z =1$

Comment: Intuitively, this problem is: find the point on the line ($ax+by+cz=1$) which optimizes the distance from the origin $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$. There isn't a maximum value, since you can travel on the line arbitrarily far away from the origin. But there ought to be a minimum, which the method of Lagrange multipliers should detect. It should be the point on the line nearest to the origin.

Comment: Add your computation to your post.  I don't see anything that should lead you to $y=0$.

Comment: Can any of you solve this? @lulu, user326210

Comment: @user326210  Are you sure?  The function in question is $x^3+y^3+z^3$ so how do you connect it to a distance?

Comment: Alright couple minutes @lulu

Comment: @lulu I just see an intuitive connection, not that the formulas are exactly the same. The analogy might let you see that there isn't a maximum, for example.

Comment: Alright this is what I got @lulu

Comment: I see the edit, but I don't see how you get to $0$  (nor how you eliminate the negative square roots). If you have $y=\sqrt {\frac  ba}\, x$ and $ z=\sqrt {\frac ca} \,x$ (trusting that $a\neq 0$) the constraint gives you $x\times (a+ b\sqrt {\frac  ba}+c\sqrt {\frac ca})=1$ so you can solve for $x$.

Comment: In the second set of equations, should that be$$3bcx^2+kabc=0$$ and similarly for the next two equations?

Comment: @lulu Is that right?  I get $y = \pm\sqrt{c\over a}|x|$ assuming $ab\neq0$  (OP has edited the second set of equations.)  If I'm not mistaken, this breaks apart into a number of cases, depending on whether $a,b,c=0$ and the choice of signs.

Comment: @saulspatz  Yes, that's right.  I just wrote down $x$ for one choice of signs (and I assume one is meant to take $abc\neq 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x \ge 0, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$ to assure a bounded solution, we have from the stationary conditions

$$
x = \sqrt\frac{\lambda a}{3}\\
y = \sqrt\frac{\lambda b}{3}\\
z = \sqrt\frac{\lambda c}{3}\\
$$

and substituting into the restriction

$$
\frac{\lambda}{3} = \frac{1}{(a\sqrt a+b\sqrt b+c\sqrt c)^2}
$$

but

$$
x^3+y^3+z^3 = \left(\frac{\lambda}{3}\right)^{\frac 32}(a\sqrt a+b\sqrt b+c\sqrt c)
$$

hence

$$
\left\{\min_{x>0,y>0,z>0}(x^3+y^3+z^3)\ \ \mbox{s. t.}\ \ \ ax+by+cz=1\right\} = \frac{1}{(a\sqrt a+ b\sqrt b+c\sqrt c)^2}
$$

Now the bordered Hessian

$$
H_g = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -a & -b & -c \\
 -a & 6 x & 0 & 0 \\
 -b & 0 & 6 y & 0 \\
 -c & 0 & 0 & 6 z \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

has value

$$
\det(H_g) = -36 \left(a^2 y z+b^2 x z+c^2 x y\right)
$$

Which with $x>0,y>0,z>0$ characterizes a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely a distillation of the comments.  As lulu suggested, I am assuming $abc\neq0$.  If this is not valid, then you have to assume each is $0$ in turn, and apply Lagrange multipliers.

We have $$\begin{align}3x^2&=-ka\\3y^2&=-kb\\3z^2&=-kc\end{align}$$  We must have $k\neq0$ for otherwise $x=y=z=0$ and the constraint is not satisfied.  Therefore, the left-hand sides in these equations are all positive, and $a,b,c$ all have the same sign.  If this is the case, then taking square roots as you have done is justified.  If not, there is no local minimum.

Your equations $$\begin{align}
z &= \sqrt{\frac{cy^2}{b}}\\
x &= \sqrt{\frac{ay^2}{b}}\end{align}$$ are correct, so far as they go. We have $$\begin{align}
z &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{c}{b}}|y|\\
x &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}|y|\end{align}$$

and of course $$y=\pm|y|$$  If we express the constraint in terms of $|y|$, that gives $8$ local minima.

There will not, in general, be a global minimum.  For example, if $$(a,b,c)=\left(\frac14,\frac12,\frac14\right)$$ then $$(x,y,z)=(0,n,4-2n)$$ satisfies the constaints and $$x^3+y^3+z^3=n^3+(4-2n)^3$$ has no global minimum.